# Loop counter within ACF Flexible Field

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) and I have a flexible content section setup.

I'm trying to loop a counter so I can add a unique id to each tab section.

Here is my code and what I have tried. I have attempted to add an outer loop to the program accordion div in order to loop the counter number without much luck.

```
elseif ( get_row_layout() == 'program_accordion') : $counter = 0;               

       while ( has_sub_field('program_accordion') ) :

         $counter++; ?>

        <div class="program-accordion">

          <input id="tab-<?php echo $counter ?>" type="checkbox" name="tabs">

          <label for="tab-"><?php the_sub_field('accordion_title'); ?></label>

          <div class="tab-content">

          <?php the_sub_field('program_description_accordion');

                if( have_rows('accordion_speaker_fields')) :

                while( have_rows('accordion_speaker_fields')) : the_row();  ?>                          
                  <img src="<?php the_sub_field('accordion_image'); ?>">

                  <?php the_sub_field('accordion_lightbox_content'); ?>                                             

                <?php 

                endwhile;                                           

                endif; ?>

           </div>

           </div>

    <?php 

    endwhile;

    endif;
```

I have been trying to run through the documentation here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/has_sub_field/ and here: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/unique-ids-for-each-layout-row/ but I'm just hitting a bit of a wall.

I'm wondering if it has to do with the fields I am calling and whether those are accurate as no content is displaying . My fields in ACF have been setup as per the image below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: ACF Field Setup]

Comment: The only place you're using `$counter` is in the `id` field. Are you sure it's not showing up there correctly? Are you sure that your `while()` loop actually needs to execute more than once?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't appear to be showing the <div class="program-accordion"></div>. I tried removing the first while loop which means the <div> shows, however the id seems to just remain as 1. I believe I need the second while loop as I'm running another repeater field inside the flexible content field but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem or do you need more help? If it solved your problem, could you accept the answer so that the question is closed, or if you need more help please add a comment and I'll take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your while loops.

The `while(has_sub_field('program_accordion'))` loop does nothing because program_accordion is just the layout name so doesn't have sub fields.

Your field structure means that each program_accordion has exactly one tab, so I assume you want the counter to increment for all tabs, and not just for tabs within each program_accordion (because they would always be 1 in that case). Therefore you also need to move the counter initialisation outside the main while loop, so you don't reset it for each tab.

(If you're having problems, it helps to print out all the ACF fields to see the structure more clearly i.e. `print_r(get_fields());`)

Based on that assumption, the following will increment the counter for each tab:

```
$counter = 0; 
// I presume this is your outer loop...
if( get_field('description_container') ):
    while( has_sub_field("description_container") ): 

    if (/* whatever condition you had here */):

    elseif ( get_row_layout() == 'program_accordion') : 
        // REMOVE THIS LOOP:
        // while ( has_sub_field('program_accordion') ) : 

         $counter++; ?>

        <div class="program-accordion">
            // display accordion content here
            // FYI, you're missing the $counter var from your label
        </div>

    <?php 
    // endwhile; - of removed loop
    endif; 
endwhile;
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain things through. The print_r will definitely come in handy in the future :)